# Read response content from gorilla toolkit Client.get

Tags: go, gorilla

I´m using [Gorilla Toolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/http) for golang to request a web resource (GET) and I want to process the response body but don´t know how to access it. Here is my main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gorilla/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "http://ubuntu.com"

    status, h, r, err := http.DefaultClient.Get(url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if r != nil {
        defer r.Close()
    }
    log.Printf("Status: %v", status)
    log.Printf("Headers: %v", h)

    var p []byte
    _, err = r.Read(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("MSG: %v", p)
}
```

Gorillas response object is of the type `io.ReadCloser` and I can´t wrap my head around how to access it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ioutil.ReadAll](https://godoc.org/io/ioutil#ReadAll) to read the entire response body as a []byte:

```
status, h, r, err := http.DefaultClient.Get(url, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
var p []byte
if r != nil {
    p, err = ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    r.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I suggest that you use the [net/http client](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client) instead of the Gorilla client.  There are more examples of how use the net/http client and the net/http client better maintained.